# Void pointers in a Linked List in C

Tags: c, linked-list, function-pointers, nodes, void-pointers

I have a program which has a function that returns a void * to a structure, but I think I'm overlooking something when casting the data.

This function creates a structure which contains a string and int. The strings are read in from a file.

```
void * buildWord(FILE * fin)
{
     void * ptr;

     char buf[100];
     Words * nw = (Words *)calloc(1, sizeof(Words));

     fgets(buf, 100, fin);
     strip(buf);
     nw->word = (char *)calloc(1, (strlen(buf) + 1));
     nw->length = strlen(buf);

     strcpy(nw->word, buf);

     ptr = &nw;

     return ptr;
}
```

Here is the function that calls this and accepts the void *.

```
Node * buildNode(FILE * in, void *(*buildData)(FILE * in) )
{
     Node * nn = (Node *)calloc(1, sizeof(Node));

     nn->data = (Words*)((*buildData)(in));
     return nn;
}
```

Here is the structure for Node

```
struct node
{
     void * data;
     struct node * next;
};
typedef struct node Node;
```

I know the creation of the word structure is fine, but when I go to work with the nodes in the list, there is no data within it. I'm not sure why that is. Thanks!

Comment: `ptr = &nw;` should be `ptr = nw;` (`nw` is already a pointer)

Comment: Also, please learn *Not* to cast the return of malloc/calloc, etc. `Words * nw = (Words *)calloc(1, sizeof(Words));` should be `Words * nw = calloc(1, sizeof(Words));` or just  `Words * nw = calloc(1, sizeof *nw);` `malloc/calloc` return nothing more than the starting address to a newly created block of memory. It's just an address, not a `char` address or an `int` address -- just an address.

Comment: Since you tagged this as `C++`, why not just use `std::list<Words>`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Your comment makes sense if the OP would remove the `C++` tag.  If the OP is using `C++`, then the casts are necessary.  And if the OP *is* using C++, then drop all of this and use `std::list`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, and sorry about the c++ tag. This is indeed in c. I removed the tag.

Comment: Agreed - somewhat of a sticky wicket trying to hit both tags at once. From the code itself, it looks like he is talking about C.

Comment: @Sturminator you can remove and replace the `nw->word` allocation and `strcpy` with `nw->words = strdup (buf);` (it allocates and copies at once)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need couple of changes.

1. The value returned from `buildData` is not right. Instead of

   ```
   ptr = &nw; // This is the address of nw. It will be
              // a dangling pointer once the function returns.

   return ptr;
   ```

   you can use

   ```
   return nw;
   ```

   You can get rid of `ptr` from the function.
2. Since the value returned from `buildData` is a different pointer than what you had used, the use of the returned value of `buildData` needs to be changed too. Instead of

   ```
   nn->data = (Words*)((*buildData)(in));
   ```

   you need to use:

   ```
   nn->data = (Words*)buildData(in));
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Your function `buildword` declares a variable `ptr` which is local to the scope of the fucntion.So when you return it the memory assigned for the variable is released which gives to the rise of dangling pointer.

So rather instead of using

```
ptr = &nw;
return ptr;
```

do

`return (void*)nw`;